# To change TYPE to nothing from conf in Vim

Tags: vim, types, syntax-highlighting, markdown

My syntax -highlighting is broken for a file which Type is conf as follows:

**File where the syntax highlighting does not work**

[alt text http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/bugs/vim-bug-type.png](http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/bugs/vim-bug-type.png)

The syntax highlighting works for all other files with the extension .markdown. However, the only difference between these files is that the other files' type is nothing, while that of a file, which has bug, its Conf.

**File where the syntax highlighting works**

[alt text http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/bugs/vim-bug-syntax2.png](http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/bugs/vim-bug-syntax2.png)

**How can you change the Type to nothing from Conf in Vim?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
:setf none
```

or (equivalently):

```
:set ft=
```

If you want to do it automatically, you'll need to configure the syntax detection.  Create a file (if it doesn't exist): vimfiles/after/filetype.vim or ~/.vim/after/filetype.vim.  In this file, add the following line:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.markdown        set ft=none
```

Alternatively, download the markdown syntax from [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1242) (I've not tried this) and configure with:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.markdown        set ft=mkd
```

For more information:

```
:help :setf
:help 'filetype'
:help :autocmd
:help BufRead
:help BufNewFile
```

For information, the problem arises because the `.markdown` extension is not recognised, so Vim looks at the contents to try to determine what the file type is.  Presumably there is something in your file that looks a little like a configuration file, so it does its best guess.  The guess is carried out in the system `filetype.vim`, typically in c:\vim\vim72 or /usr/share/vim/vim72/filetype.vim (I think) and looks like this:

```
" Generic configuration file (check this last, it's just guessing!)
au BufNewFile,BufRead,StdinReadPost *
    \ if !did_filetype() && expand("<amatch>") !~ g:ft_ignore_pat
    \    && (getline(1) =~ '^#' || getline(2) =~ '^#' || getline(3) =~ '^#'
    \   || getline(4) =~ '^#' || getline(5) =~ '^#') |
    \   setf conf |
    \ endif
```

This checks whether any of the first five lines start with a `#` and if they do and no other filetype has been matched, it sets the filetype to `conf`.

Comment: You answer solves the "how-to" -part of the problem. Thanks for that! --- It seems that the problem is elsewhere, since the syntax highlighting does not get right. I am using these markdown codes: http://plasticboy.com/markdown-vim-mode/

Comment: I found the cause of the bug. The .mkd -file has a bug which breaks the syntax highlighting if `#` is the first character in the document. --- Bug reports are at http://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown/issues

Answer (score 3):

```
:set filetype=
```

will set the file type to none.